# Replied to a Craigslist Spammer

Tags: credit

So I did just about the dumbest thing today - I was looking for apartments on Craigslist (I’ve always stayed away but a friend of mine just got one from there) and reply to one ad with my email. They replied back saying it’s still available for rent and a bunch of questions for me to fill out.
Basically they got my:
Full name
Current address 
Cell phone number
DOB
Workplace 
Apparently this scam has been going a while, this guy says he’s working for Serving In Mission (one search on google and I should have seen it all ugh). 
The most worrying question I pathetically answered without thinking was “do you work late nights?” And I said sometimes I close. (Again, I gave my current address)
I gave no credit or card numbers, no ssn or anything but that yeah. I haven’t had an email back all day and the ads been flagged already. Should I be as worried as I am?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about personal finance.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, since you gave them part of your identity, and when you aren't home so they can rob you.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: not the downvoter, but probably the would-be robber downvoted in the hopes nobody would see your reply